# SQL relation with 2 foreign key of the same table

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, relation

I want to create a table that contain 2 foreign key that references on the same field of the same table:

I've the table "nation" and the table "relation"

2 nations form a relation like "**USA** and **Russia** are **Neutral**"

i made with

```
create table relation( 
id int(3) primary key,
nation1 int(3),
foreign key (nation1) references nation(id),
nation2 int(3),
foreign key (nation2) references nation(id),
type int(1)
);
```

thats works but

1. i can create ambiguous records simply inverting nation1 and nation2 values like:

   ```
   1 USA RUSSIA 0 
   2 RUSSIA USA 1
   ```
2. i can't make effective queries like

   ```
   SELECT nation1.name,nation2.name,relation.type
   FROM nation.relation
   WHERE relation.type = "0"
   AND nation.name = "USA"
   AND nation.id = relation.nation1
   ```

because "USA" can be under "nation2"

How can i resolve those 2 problems?

Comment: your table is very restricted for your requirements. add another column instead like `category char(1)` values N = neutral
then use that for your query `AND category = 'N'`

Comment: I'd use relation.type where 2-allies, 1-friends, 0-neutral, -1-Hostile, -2-Enemies